# How do I change the values in a 2d array using 1d array?

Tags: c++

I want to make the values of `num[]` replace all of the  `a[][]` values when one of the numbers equal `k`. So all the values of `num` correspond to each place at `k`. So for example when `k` reaches 20 if there is a 20 in the 2d array I want to replace all 20's with whatever is in `num[19]`, but whenever I try it that, they all become skewed numbers and I can't find the reason why. Are my for loops set up wrong or what else could be the problem?

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
//other code that uses a file to make 2d array
int width, height, maxval;
fin >> P2 >> width >> height >> maxval;
int **a = new int *[height];
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    a[i] = new int[width];
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        fin >> a[i][j];
    }
}

}


void eq(int **a, int h, int w) {

    int num[255];
double num1[255];
double prob[255], cumul[255]{ 0 };
double x, y, z=0;
for (int k = 1; k <= 255; k++)
{
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {//counts the repeated pixel values 
            if (pix[i][j] == k)
            {
                temp += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    num1[k - 1] = temp;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {

    prob[i] = (num1[i] / (height*width));//show the decimal number of how many pixel values are in the image over the total
    cout << prob[i] << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    y = prob[i];
    x = y + z;
    z = x;// adds all the probabilities to make the sum
    cumul[i] =x;    
    cout << cumul[i] << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {

    num[i] =floor(cumul[i]*255);// converts the cumulative number to the new pixel value and sets it in a array

}

    for (int k = 1; k <= 255; k++) {//loop that is not coming out right
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {

                if (a[i][j] == k)
                {
                    a[i][j] =num[k-1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I am making a function that deals with histogram equalization to make a pgm image clearer. In the main function I am calling a pgm file and setting all the pixel values into a 2d array. So the `num[]` is the part where I make the new pixel values, but for some reason whenever I call for example `a[0][0]` I should be getting something that is not zero or 255 since both of those values mean that none of the pixels had that corresponding intensity, but whenever I call it I get 255 or some other random number.

Comment: I asume the a[][] and num[] are full when you make this?

Comment: Yea a[][] is a pointer that I fill in the main function and num[] is made in the void

Comment: Can you show me please (1) How is a[][] declared and on what scope and (2) the output you're getting.

Comment: I inputted the a[][] code, but I am pretty sure that's not causing the problem since it works fine in my other function and changes as well.

Comment: There is no evident problem here. You should build a [mcve] so that we can test your real code.

Comment: What are "skewed" numbers? Example input and output would be helpful.

Comment: I added the rest of the function since that might be the problem and I also added comments to what each for loop does and what the function does in it's entirety.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you want to do, this line :

```
a[i][j] =num[i];
```

should be :

```
a[i][j] =num[k-1];
```

Because you want:

```
if( a[i][j] = k = 20){
  a[i][j] = num[k-1 = 19] 
 }
```

Comment: Sorry that was typo on my part and that still doesn't I tried already. Thanks though.